# Cannot make HTTP Delete request with Ruby's net/http library

Tags: ruby, http

I've been trying to make an API call to my server to delete a user record help on a dev database.  When I use Fiddler to call the URL with the DELETE operation I am able to immediately delete the user record. When I call that same URL, again with the DELETE operation, from my script below, I get this error:

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'."}

I have changed the url in my script below. The url I am using is definitely correct. I suspect that there is a logical error in my code that I haven't caught. My script:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
require 'uri'

def deleteUserRole
  # prepare request

  url= "http://my.database.5002143.access"    # dev
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.path)
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

  # send the request
  response = http.request(request)

  puts "response: \n"
  puts response.body
  puts "response code: " + response.code + "\n \n"

  # parse response
  buffer= response.body
  result = JSON.parse(buffer)

  status= result["Success"]
  if status == true
  then puts "passed"
  else puts "failed"
  end
end

deleteUserRole
```

Comment: The message says that the problem is on the API, not the request itself, `The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'`

Comment: The code I put above is a small part of a script that's about 1000 lines long and hits close to 20 different API calls, doing GETs, POSTs, PUTs, and DELETEs. Every single DELETE call fails when called from my script, but works just fine when put into Fiddler and called individually.  There is some difference between what my script is doing and what Fiddler is doing. I suspect it has to do with the request-headers being sent through my script VS through Fiddler.

Comment: I found out what my problem was.  I needed to do: `request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri)` instead.  This immediately solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was typing in the wrong command.  I needed to change this line:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.path)
```

to this line:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri)
```

By typing `uri.path` I was excluding part of the URL from the API call.  When I was debugging, I would type `puts uri` and that would show me the full URL, so I was certain the URL was right.  The URL *was* right, but I was not including the full URL in my DELETE call.

Answer (score 0):

if you miss the parameters to pass while requesting delete, it won't work

you can do like this

```
uri = URI.parse('http://localhost/test')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
attribute_url = '?'
attribute_url << body.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join('&')
request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new(uri.request_uri+attribute_url)
response = http.request(request)
```

where body is a hashmap where you can define query params as a hashmap.. while sending request it can be joined in the url by the code above.

ex:`body = { :resname => 'res', :bucket_name => 'bucket', :uploaded_by => 'upload' }`